# Android: put something on top of linear layout

Tags: android, layout, hide, android-linearlayout

What I want to do is show a "frame" (or new layout) on top of "2" (second LinearLayout), when a button would be pressed. How should I do it? Precreate it and make it somehow hidden if button not pressed?

I have this type of layout:

[image: layout]

**XML:**

```
<LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout>
        //here would be another view, only shown when a button is clicked
        <ViewFlipper>
        </ViewFlipper>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout      
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show any view on button click then first put that view inside xml and make its visibility gone, and on button click make it visible. I have put imageview inside your code which visibility is set as gone so it wont show in layout.

```
<LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout>
        //here would be another view, only shown when a button is clicked
         <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon"
                        android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout      
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

For making image view visible,

```
imag1.seVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Thank you, will do it this way.

Answer (score 5):

Use `FrameLayout` to show `view` over-lapping another `view`. You can keep the view as `INVISIBLE` or using `GONE` in the xml and then just make it visible when the `Button` is Clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Yes...you should prepare it in xml and give it an id.then you can easily manage its visibility on button click using `mLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);` and `mLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` like:

```
Button mButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame_layout);

static int count=0;
mButton.setOnClick.... (new OnClick...()

          public void onClick(){

              count++;
              if(count==1)             
                   ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);              
              else
              {
                   count=0;
                   ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              }
          }        
);
```

Comment: I think in place of 'if(count==1)' ..we just can use 'if(ll.isShown())'

Answer (score 2):

Here you have two options:

As you said pre-create layouts and set visibility to Visibility_Gone to layouts initially, not to be shown, set Visibitlity to View.Visible to display the layouts.

Another approach is to create views dynamically, and adding to parent on specified index, like to add on top of linearlayout use:

```
linearLayout.addView(view, 0);
```